# python : count the number of people by division (department) thats in a building in half hour slots

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset that has a line for each employee clocking in and corresponding clock-out into the company premises.

[image: sample data]

I want to create a matrix (summary) of how many people from each division are in the building in half hourly time slots as shown below:

[image]

I've written the code for how many people are in the building in half hour slots but i cant figure out how to work out how many people in each division are in the building in those slots.  I've tried numerous different techniques but i cant figure the thing out.  I've written the code below for a total of how many people in the building:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp # import pandas date time 
# import a few rows of data.   our actual real data is much larger
sample_data = pd.DataFrame({'direction_in': {37196: Timestamp('2019-09-26 16:11:11'), 2364: Timestamp('2019-09-03 13:37:48'), 36266: Timestamp('2018-04-05 06:06:14'), 27159: Timestamp('2019-09-04 07:31:22'), 48518: Timestamp('2018-09-05 05:44:46')}, 'emp': {37196: 152.0, 2364: 10.0, 36266: 150.0, 27159: 115.0, 48518: 187.0}, 'direction_out': {37196: Timestamp('2019-09-26 16:32:20'), 2364: Timestamp('2019-09-03 22:21:04'), 36266: Timestamp('2018-04-05 18:15:21'), 27159: Timestamp('2019-09-04 15:58:02'), 48518: Timestamp('2018-09-05 15:51:51')}, 'time_difference': {37196: '0 days 00:21:09', 2364: '0 days 08:43:16', 36266: '0 days 12:09:07', 27159: '0 days 08:26:40', 48518: '0 days 10:07:05'}, 'complete_record': {37196: 'yes', 2364: 'yes', 36266: 'yes', 27159: 'yes', 48518: 'yes'}, 'terminal': {37196: 1.0, 2364: 1.0, 36266: 1.0, 27159: 1.0, 48518: 3.0}, 'job_title': {37196: 59.0, 2364: 14.0, 36266: 83.0, 27159: 82.0, 48518: 4.0}, 'division': {37196: 2.0, 2364: 1.0, 36266: 2.0, 27159: 1.0, 48518: 4.0}})

# Create a new dataframe the sumerised data. 
# The dataframe will contain 30 minute intervals from the first date to the last date in the above data 

department_clocked_in_matrix = pd.DataFrame() # Creates new dataframe 
department_clocked_in_matrix["date_time_from"] = pd.date_range(start="2018-02-12 00:00:00",end="2019-12-09 23:30:00",freq='30min') # Create from column 
department_clocked_in_matrix['date_time_to'] = (department_clocked_in_matrix['date_time_from'].shift(-1)).fillna(0) # Creates to_column, 30 minutes distance from the from column

# chop off the last value as it shows a zero value 
department_clocked_in_matrix = department_clocked_in_matrix.iloc[0:-1]
department_clocked_in_matrix


def sum_function(temp_df): 
    temp_sample = sample_data.loc[(temp_df.date_time_from >= sample_data.direction_in ) & (temp_df.date_time_to <= sample_data.direction_out),["division"] ].count()
    return temp_sample 

department_clocked_in_matrix2 = department_clocked_in_matrix.apply(sum_function, axis=1)  # axis one is accross column summing 
department_clocked_in_matrix["count"] = department_clocked_in_matrix2["division"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first build a dataframe from each row in the original dataframe (`sample_data`) per period of 30 minutes, keeping the division and concatenate all those dataframes. By counting the lines per hour and division and pivoting the dataframe, I would get the presences and count per division.

From that point, it would be enough to merge that into the `department_clocked_in_matrix.merge` and add a `total` column to get the expected data.

Code could be:

```
tmp = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'count': 1, 'division':row.division},
             index = pd.date_range(row['direction_in'].floor('30T'),
                       row['direction_out'].ceil('30T'),
                       freq='30T', name='date_time_from'))
    for _, row in sample_data.iterrows()], sort=True).reset_index()

resul = tmp.groupby(['date_time_from', 'division']).sum().unstack()
#.reindex(
#    columns=[str(i) for i in range(1, 9)]).fillna(0).astype('int')

resul.columns = [str(int(i[1])) for i in resul.columns]
resul = resul.reindex(columns=[str(i) for i in range(1,9)])

resul = department_clocked_in_matrix.merge(resul, how='left', on='date_time_from'
                                           ).fillna(0)
resul = resul.set_index(['date_time_from', 'date_time_to']).astype('int')
resul = resul.assign(total=resul.sum(axis=1)).reset_index()
```

It displays as:

```
           date_time_from        date_time_to  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  total
0     2018-02-12 00:00:00 2018-02-12 00:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
1     2018-02-12 00:30:00 2018-02-12 01:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
2     2018-02-12 01:00:00 2018-02-12 01:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
3     2018-02-12 01:30:00 2018-02-12 02:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
4     2018-02-12 02:00:00 2018-02-12 02:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
5     2018-02-12 02:30:00 2018-02-12 03:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
6     2018-02-12 03:00:00 2018-02-12 03:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
7     2018-02-12 03:30:00 2018-02-12 04:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
8     2018-02-12 04:00:00 2018-02-12 04:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
9     2018-02-12 04:30:00 2018-02-12 05:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
...                   ...                 ... .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..    ...
31957 2019-12-09 18:30:00 2019-12-09 19:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31958 2019-12-09 19:00:00 2019-12-09 19:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31959 2019-12-09 19:30:00 2019-12-09 20:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31960 2019-12-09 20:00:00 2019-12-09 20:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31961 2019-12-09 20:30:00 2019-12-09 21:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31962 2019-12-09 21:00:00 2019-12-09 21:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31963 2019-12-09 21:30:00 2019-12-09 22:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31964 2019-12-09 22:00:00 2019-12-09 22:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31965 2019-12-09 22:30:00 2019-12-09 23:00:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
31966 2019-12-09 23:00:00 2019-12-09 23:30:00  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      0

[31967 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Genius.  Thanks :-)   I didn't understand your answer at first.  I realized my logic was all wrong i.e. the line `temp_sample = sample_data.loc[(temp_df.date_time_from >= sample_data.direction_in ) & (temp_df.date_time_to <= sample_data.direction_out),["division"] ].count()"` cant work.  Once i figured that out, i didn't understand the code but after looking at it for a while and taking it apart i now understand it - I had to re-write it in python functions and less pandas to understand it, then i understand why you did it the way you did, so much quicker writing in pure pandas.

Comment: how do i get something like this into a more pandas friendly code: `index = pd.date_range("2020/04/13 08:00","2020/04/13 17:00",freq='30T', name='date_time_from')
if min(index) != max(index): 
    index = index.drop(max(index)) # drop index because person was not in the building for the final half hour  
else: 
    index = index # the employee clocked in and out within half an hour so only value`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not too pretty but it should do the expected. 
I took **your approach** of filtering the *sample_data* by each row (30 minute interval) of the *department_clocked_in_matrix* and just used additionally `groupby()` 
**Output**

```
Out[5]: 
          date_time_from        date_time_to    1    2    3    4    5
120  2019-09-03 12:00:00 2019-09-03 12:30:00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
121  2019-09-03 12:30:00 2019-09-03 13:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
122  2019-09-03 13:00:00 2019-09-03 13:30:00  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
123  2019-09-03 13:30:00 2019-09-03 14:00:00  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
124  2019-09-03 14:00:00 2019-09-03 14:30:00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

**Code**

```
from pandas import Timestamp # import pandas date time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample_data = pd.DataFrame({'direction_in': {37196: Timestamp('2019-09-03 13:11:11'), 2364: Timestamp('2019-09-03 13:37:48'), 36266: Timestamp('2019-09-03 13:06:14'), 27159: Timestamp('2019-09-04 07:31:22'), 48518: Timestamp('2018-09-05 05:44:46')}, 'emp': {37196: 152.0, 2364: 10.0, 36266: 150.0, 27159: 115.0, 48518: 187.0}, 'direction_out': {37196: Timestamp('2019-09-04 07:31:22'), 2364: Timestamp('2019-09-03 22:21:04'), 36266: Timestamp('2019-09-04 07:31:22'), 27159: Timestamp('2019-09-04 07:31:22'), 48518: Timestamp('2019-09-04 07:31:22')}, 'time_difference': {37196: '0 days 00:21:09', 2364: '0 days 08:43:16', 36266: '0 days 12:09:07', 27159: '0 days 08:26:40', 48518: '0 days 10:07:05'}, 'complete_record': {37196: 'yes', 2364: 'yes', 36266: 'yes', 27159: 'yes', 48518: 'yes'}, 'terminal': {37196: 1.0, 2364: 1.0, 36266: 1.0, 27159: 1.0, 48518: 3.0}, 'job_title': {37196: 59.0, 2364: 14.0, 36266: 83.0, 27159: 82.0, 48518: 4.0}, 'division': {37196: 1.0, 2364: 2.0, 36266: 3.0, 27159: 4.0, 48518: 5.0}})

department_clocked_in_matrix = pd.DataFrame() # Creates new dataframe
department_clocked_in_matrix["date_time_from"] = pd.date_range(start="2019-09-01 00:00:00",end="2019-09-30 23:30:00",freq='30min') # Create from column
department_clocked_in_matrix['date_time_to'] = (department_clocked_in_matrix['date_time_from'].shift(-1)).fillna(0) # Creates to_column, 30 minutes distance from the from column

# chop off the last value as it shows a zero value
department_clocked_in_matrix = department_clocked_in_matrix.iloc[0:-1]

possible_division = np.arange(1,6)

# for index, row in department_clocked_in_matrix[27290:27310].iterrows():
for index, row in department_clocked_in_matrix.iterrows():
    tmp_df = sample_data[(sample_data['direction_in'] >= row[0]) & (sample_data['direction_in'] <= row[1])]
    count = tmp_df.groupby('division').count().iloc[:,1]
    if not count.empty:
        for div, number in count.iteritems():
            department_clocked_in_matrix.loc[index, str(int(div))] = number

department_clocked_in_matrix.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

**Note:**
I Changed the sample data a litte bit to make it easerie to verfiy the results